# Refactor how one options hash is built from another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This code is written for ActiveAdmin, but actually it does not matter.
How I can optimize it? Thank you.

```
module ActiveAdminSimpleMenu
  # in options can take:
  # menu_priority:integer
  # menu_parent:string
  # permitted_params:array for some additions to main_fields permitted params

  def simple_menu_for(klass, options = {})
    ActiveAdmin.register klass do
      menu_options = {}
      menu_options[:priority] = options[:menu_priority] if options[:menu_priority]
      menu_options[:parent] = options[:menu_parent] if options[:menu_parent]
      menu menu_options unless menu_options.empty?
      permit_params(*(klass.main_fields + (options[:permitted_params] ? options[:permitted_params] : [])))
      ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume by "optimize" you mean refactor. You can

- use `Hash#slice` (a Rails method) to build `menu_options`
- eliminate the double negative by using `if` and `any?`
- use `||` to test `options[:permitted_params]`

All together:

```
def simple_menu_for(klass, options = {})
  ActiveAdmin.register klass do
    menu_options = options.slice(:menu_priority, :menu_parent)
    menu menu_options if menu_options.any?
    permit_params(*(klass.main_fields + (options[:permitted_params] || [])))
    ...
```